# Magento - how to add custom variables to new order E-mail?

Tags: magento

I need to add custom variable to new order E-mail.

This variables are custom customer attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like any other variable that you are using you can ask variables from your object so if you do in php

```
<?php echo $customerObject->getMyCustomVariable();?>
```

you would do in template

```
{{var customerObject.getMyCustomVariable()}}
```

And as in php side you have to be sure that this attribute exists in your object and is included in collection

Comment: I have created a cutom function to do that : 

` public function getCustomerKundennummer() {
 
  if (!$this->getCustomerId()) return;
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load( $this->getCustomerId());
  $kundennummer = $customer->getData('kundennummer');
  return ($kundennummer);
 } 
`
and in my template : 

`{{var order.getCustomerKundennummer()}}`

Thank you for help :)

Comment: vote it up if it helps you then others will find the solution more easily

Comment: Where did you place this public function?

Comment: The following function can be inserted in: ../Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php.