# Customer IP address on Magento Order Email

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

The customer's IP address is stored against the order record in the back end of Magento (ver 1.7.0.2 but it is not available as a variable to add to the New Order Confirmation Email.

Can anyone help me change the email template so that I can get this field added to the email?

Many thanks

Comment: U can change default email template from /app/locale/en_US/template/email/

Comment: How to add new field value in email template for this check http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/add-custom-fields-in-contact-us-form-in-magento/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393479/add-custom-attribute-in-order-email-templates-magento

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the links do not really help.  I am not looking to a new custom variable.  The IP address already exists against every customer order.  I understand how to change the order email template but I am looking for a way of getting this field that already exists on to the template.  Thanks

Comment: ok..so u want pass your custom variable (ip address) in order mail.right!do u check this three links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358971/magento-how-to-add-custom-variables-to-new-order-e-mail , http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2010/04/add-new-variable-to-order-update-e-mail.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393479/add-custom-attribute-in-order-email-templates-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 months late maybe, but is this what you're looking for?

```
$order->getRemoteIp()
```

I've not tried it in the context of an email template but I'd guess this:

```
{{var remote_ip}}
```

or failing that, try:

```
{{var order.getRemoteIp()}}
```

FWIW I found the getRemoteIp() function used in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml.